# Java float auto rounding issue

Tags: java

I have a simple method to calculate the equivalentRate but I've ran into a problem where is seems to be rounding unnecessarily.

When I pass in 99.002 it should return something like 9920.040080160

99.002 / (100 – 99.002) x 100

But for some reason its rounding to three decimal place. It seems to be matching the number of decimal places of the argument rate.

```
  public float calculateEquivalentRate(float rate){
        if(rate==100) {
           return 0.000F;
        }
        return rate / (100 - rate) * 100;
    }
```

Any ideas how I can stop the rounding?

Comment: Floats have a limited precision. If it's not enough, you can switch to doubles. If that's not enough you can use something with arbitrary precision, like a BigDecimal.

Comment: the calculation you are doing has a non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result - there must be some rounding or you must work with a rational number (fraction)

Comment: *"it should return something like 9920.040080160"* Since a `float` only has [**6 to 9** significant decimal digits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), it's ***impossible*** for a `float` to store a number like that, which has **13** significant decimal digits of precision.

Answer (score 2):

Floats have a limited precision. If it's not enough, you can switch to doubles. If that's not enough you can use something with arbitrary precision, like a BigDecimal.

Switching from float to double seems to give you the precision you want:

```
double rate = 99.002;
System.out.println(rate / (100-rate) * 100);
```

Ouput:

```
9920.040080160274
```